# Zorn's Lemma and injective choice functions

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be a set and let ${\cal E}\subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ be a collection of non-empty subset. We say that a map $f: {\cal E}\to X$ is an *injective choice function* if it is injective and
 $f(e) \in e$ for all $e\in {\cal E}$.

I want to prove the following maximality statement:

(S) If $X$ is a set and ${\cal E}\subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ has an injective choice function, then there is ${\cal E}_1 \subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ with ${\cal E}_1\supseteq {\cal E}$ such that

1. ${\cal E}_1$ has an injective choice function, and
2. if $u \in {\cal P}(X)\setminus ({\cal E}_1\cup\{\emptyset\})$ then ${\cal E}_1\cup \{u\}$ has no injective choice function.

My gut feeling is that this is a pretty straightforward application of Zorn's Lemma - but I can't make the self-map work on the union of a chain of ${\cal E}$'s...! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see what goes wrong if you take as poset partial injective choice functions with $\mathcal E$ in their domain, use Zorn's lemma to get a maximal element, and take $\mathcal E_1$ to be its domain

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: The maximum element that you get can’t be extended, but there may be some other injective choice function on a properly larger domain.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott wouldn't that contradict maximality?

Comment: @KarthikKannan: No. The fact that a particular function cannot be extended to a larger domain without losing injectivity doesn’t mean that there isn’t some completely different injective choice function with a larger domain.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott doesn't Zorn's Lemma assert that the set of all such maximal functions (say $\mathcal{F}$) is non-empty? So shouldn't any other maximal function already be included in this $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @KarthikKannan: Doesn’t matter. We don’t just want a maximal function: we want a maximal **domain**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s false. Let $X=\omega$, for $n\in\omega$ let $e_n=\omega\setminus n$, and let $\mathscr{E}=\{e_n:n\in\omega\}$. Suppose that $\mathscr{E}_1\supseteq\mathscr{E}$ has an injective choice function $f$, and let $a=\{f(e_n):n\in\omega\}$. Let $\{a_0,a_1\}$ be a partition of $a$ such that $|a_0|=|a_1|=\omega$; clearly $a_0\notin\mathscr{E}_1$, so let $\mathscr{E}_2=\mathscr{E}_1\cup\{a_0\}\supsetneqq\mathscr{E}_1$.

Recursively define $\varphi:\omega\to a_1$ as follows: if $\varphi\upharpoonright n$ has been defined for some $n\in\omega$, let

$$\varphi(n)=\min\{k\in a_1:k\in e_n\setminus\varphi[n]\}\;;$$

then $\varphi$ is an injective choice function for $\mathscr{E}$, and $\operatorname{ran}\varphi\subseteq a_1$.

Let

$$g:\mathscr{E}_2\to\omega:e\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(e),&\text{if }e\in\mathscr{E}_1\setminus\mathscr{E}\\
\min a_0,&\text{if }e=a_0\\
\varphi(n),&\text{if }n\in\omega\text{ and }e=e_n\;;
\end{cases}$$

then $g$ is an injective choice function for $\mathscr{E}_2$. Thus, there is no $\mathscr{E}_1$ extending $\mathscr{E}$ that is maximal with respect to having an injective choice function.

Comment: I just want to confirm that you are assuming that $a_0$ and $a_1$ are disjoint. Further, do you mean that $\varphi\circ (\text{min}_{A\subseteq\omega}\upharpoonright \mathscr{E})$ is an injective choice function on $\mathscr{E}$?

Comment: @KarthikKannan: Yes, they were supposed to be disjoint; I’ve fixed that. I don’t understand your notation; $e_n\mapsto\varphi(n)$ is an injective choice function for $\mathscr{E}$.

Comment: that is what I meant. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KarthikKannan: You’re welcome!

Comment: @bof: That's right; I wasn't yet entirely sure exactly where I was going at that point, so I left myself some room.

Comment: Wow thanks, amazing! I was convinced this was standard Zorn....!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: My pleasure: that one was interesting.

Comment: For the last line of the definition of $g$, wouldn't you need to change the condition to $n\in\omega\backslash 1\mbox{ and }e=e_n$ since $\varphi(0)=\min a_0$?

Comment: @DanielWalker: $\varphi(0)=\min a_1$.

Comment: Ahhh!  My bad.  Thanks

Comment: @DanielWalker: No problem!